# Sending a webpage from google chrome extension to a desktop app

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Let's say I create a desktop note app. Is it possible to create a google extension that would be allow to communicate a selected webpage to that desktop app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want your desktop software to communicate with webpages, you can develop an [NPAPI plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins) on the user's computer. (I'd recommend starting with [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/)) Then, you can [package that into a Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) and [install that Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html) automatically with your other software. Good luck!